# JUnit Mockito framework

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I am learning the JUnit with Mockito framework, I tried writing test cases on my service code as:-

```
ChildClass childClass = (ChildClass)(employeeDao.callMethod().getClassRef());
```

JUnit test case:-

```
ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();
Mockito.when(employeeDao.callMethod().getClassRef()).thenReturn(childClass);
```

But getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Then tried splitting the method calls in two seperate statements like:-

```
ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();
Mockito.when(employeeDao.callMethod()).thenReturn(employeeInstance);
Mockito.when(employeeInstanceMocked.getClassRef()).thenReturn(childClass);
```

But still getting the object cast exception due to Mockito is returning SuperClassObject but code is casting into ChildClass Object. Is the current Java code is 100% compatible to test with JUnit test case or I am missing some point.

Comment: where do you create the mock for `employeeInstance`?

Comment: Using @Mock EmployeeInstance employeeInstance; in test class.

Comment: You've got `thenReturn(employeeInstance)` but on the next line, you're using `employeeInstanceMocked`.  Is this a misprint?  You want these to be the same.

Comment: Your first snippet is obviously going to give NullPointerException, because `callMethod()` on a mock will return null, unless you've stubbed it.  Your second snippet should work, if it's actually `employeeInstanceMocked` that you're using in your first stubbing call.  You said you got "object cast exception" - that's not an exception I'm familiar with.  What's the exact text of it?

Comment: Handler execution resulted in exception: SuperClass$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$467cd658 cannot be cast to ChildClass

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Mockito. Example from [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.10/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

```
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

// note that we're stubbing a chain of methods here: getBar().getName()
when(mock.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("deep");

// note that we're chaining method calls: getBar().getName()
assertEquals("deep", mock.getBar().getName());
```

But as mentioned in documentation it is bad practice due to violation of [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mocked class when you want a mocked object. If you want the behavior of an actual class such as the reference of the dao you tried to call you need to use spy.

Junit:

```
ChildClass childClass = Mockito.spy(new ChildClass());
```

Comment: Did you test this, or is it just a guess?